# Multi layer async control flow

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

I wonder how the thread flow in this example. There is async event handler, and  it calls another async method, which has two awaits. Can I understand the flow like this :

- 1)UI thread calls button1_Click,it sequentially calls LoadStringAsync method
- 2)LoadStringAsync calls GetFirstNameAsync first
- 3)GetFirstNameAsync returns an uncompleted Task, LoadStringAsync
  awaits this Task
- 4) LoadStringAsync in turn returns an uncompleted Task, button1_Click
  awaits the Task returned by LoadStringAsync
- 5) UI thread leaves button1_Click. This is why UI thread is not
  blocked.
- 6) When GetFirstNameAsync eventually completes, LoadStringAsync can
  continue, which means UI thread will come in again, and it execute
  next line which is another await.
- 8) GetLastNameAsync returns an uncompleted Task, LoadStringAsync
  awaits the Task returned by GetLastNameAsync
- 9) button1_Click awaits the Task returned by LoadStringAsync
- 10) UI thread leaves button1_Click again, and does something else.
- 11) the same step repeats.

Is my assumption correct ? or there is deadlock situation here.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
string s = await LoadStringAsync(); 
textBox1.Text = s; 
}

static async Task<string> LoadStringAsync() 
{ 
string firstName = await GetFirstNameAsync(); 
string lastName = await GetLastNameAsync(); 
return firstName + ” ” + lastName; 
}
```

Comment: The flow you've described seems about right.  It's impossible to tell for sure if there is not a deadlock situation here because you have not provided the details on things like LoadStringAsync, GetFirstNameAsync, etc.  If there aren't any blocking calls in there, you should be fine.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow is almost correct. Just one modification: it's not possible for a method to return twice (steps 4 and 9). Since `LoadStringAsync` has already returned an uncompleted task, it just returns directly to the UI thread at the second `await`.

There's no deadlock in the code you've provided.

Comment: Also probably worth pointing out that if he were to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on the awaits inside `LoadStringAsync()`, the UI thread won't need to be bothered again until the whole `await LoadStringAsync()` completes; a ThreadPool thread will be used for that instead.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, thanks for your comment. for last couple of days, I have been reading your blogs. I also think there is no deadlock issue, after I read your deadlock blog. However your deadlock blog has no two awaits example, then I read this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/ . My example code actually is taken from there, and Stephen Toub said it is a deadlock ( unless I totally understand his words wrong)....

Comment: @sellotape can I understand like: if .ConfigureAwait(false) is used, a thread A from threadpool will handle the two awaits inside LoadStringAsync() , thread A will return the final string to s variable in button_Click method. Then which thread will update textBox1 ? if it is not UI thread, I guess it will throw exception . –

Comment: @zhengyu - it's not as strong as "will"; it's more a case of telling the compiler that you don't need the original context back for the continuation (after the await is complete).  The task might run on a ThreadPool thread or not, but with `ConfigureAwait(true)` (or omitted, as it's the default), the _continuation_ after the task will continue in the same context, and in the case of your UI, this will also mean on the UI thread.  So my comment that it "...won't _need_ to..." doesn't mean it won't, but at least you're giving it the option not to.

Comment: @zhengyu: The deadlock is due to Toub's example of using `Result`. And as he explains in that same post, the deadlock is avoided by using `await` instead of `Result`. Which your example code already does. It doesn't matter whether there's one `await` or two.

Comment: @sellotape Thanks. I made the test and trace the thread id ( *Debug.WriteLin* ') and see how it is done. As long as the context at *button1_Click* is still original, meaning UI thread handles it, then I can add *.Configure(false)* on the two await in *LoadStringAsync()* as I want it.  If I add *.Configure(false)* at the *button1_Click()* level, it will throw exception.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks Stephen, my confusion was mainly due to my language( not my native language), but that was how I thought too.  Anyway, your blog is clear and fantastic.